# jQuery click on button will show the div and again click on any area of the page will hide the div?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have my markup something like this. It is for the button where someone will click.

```
<div class="logout-wrap">
  <div class="account-info"> <a href="../profile.php">admin ADMIN</a>
</div><!--.account-info-->
<div class="account-info-icon">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" class="account-sprited notice"><span>5</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="account-sprited profile profiletest"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

It is for the area that will by default hide and when someone will click on button it will show the div with its contents.

```
<div class="account-info-box" style="display: block;">
  <div class="top-info">
    <div class="profile-img">
      <img alt="" src="../images/profile.png">
    </div><!--.profile-img-->
    <div class="profile-text">
      <span class="username">sgsh dshjds</span>
      <span class="acctype">Account Type- Agent</span>
      <span class="view-profile"><a href="" class="profile">View Profile</a></span>
    </div><!--.profile-text-->
  </div><!--.top-info-->
  <div class="bottom-info">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="" class="profile">Create An Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="profile">Signout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--.bottom-info-->
</div>
```

Here when page loads the div for account-info-box will be hide. when I will click on profile it will show the div account-info-box. For that I have my jquery like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div.account-info-box').hide();
      jQuery('a.profile').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('div.account-info-box').show();
    });
  });
</script>
```

But here I want that when I will again click on any other area of a page it will be again hide. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

**Edit**
I have changed my jQuery code like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div.account-info-box').hide();
    jQuery('.profiletest').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery('div.account-info-box').show();
   });
 });

 jQuery(document).ready(function(event) {
  if(event.target.ClassName !== 'profiletest') {
    jQuery('div.account-info-box').hide();
  }
 });
```

Now its showing error like `TypeError: event.target is undefined`

Comment: `$(document).click`? But you have to check if you do not click on `a.profile` as that will open your `div`

Comment: Use delegated event and filter using `if($(event.target).closest(selector).length) return;` method or IMO better, use focus/blur logic of the DIV. This has already been asked, search on SO

Answer (score 0):

add this to your script inside document.ready function.

```
jQuery("body").click(function(e){ //or jQuery(document)
  if(e.target.className !== "profile")
  {
    jQuery('div.account-info-box').hide();
   }
});
```

final code.(updated)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div.account-info-box').hide();
    jQuery('a.profile').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery('div.account-info-box').show();
   });

   jQuery("body").click(function(e){ //or jQuery(document)
    if(e.target.className !== "profile")
    {
      jQuery('div.account-info-box').hide();
     }
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: yes this one is working fine but when I am reloading the age the div is showing the content. I want div.account-info-box should hide when page reloads as well.

Comment: `jQuery('div.account-info-box').hide();` did u remove this?? add this to your script...

Comment: then there is something that is breaking your code... can u create a fiddle for this ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34551/discussion-between-newuser-and-bipen)

Comment: by using your latest code the div for account-info-box is showing display none always

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/jscript">
document.Click = Hide();

//to show on button click
$(".bottom-info").Click(function(){
$(".account-info-box").attr("display","block");
});

//to hide it
Hide(function(){
$(".account-info-box").attr("display","none");
});

<script>
```